# Trying to automatically add rows daily to a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to devise a script for my Google Sheet which will add 6 new rows each day and as part of those rows calculate the total hours/sales from the date the rows were added on.

The formula would both be more or less something like this:

```
=sumif($A:$A, "="&A110, $E:$E)
```

With the **date column being A** and **E being the hours worked**.

Any help on this would be much appreciated, I have been struggling with it for a while now as I'm not very experience using the script editor.

Comment: Include your current script and where you are struggling.

Comment: where's your code?